# Get row to swap tables on a certain condition

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, triggers, constraints, plpgsql

I currently have a parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    member_id SERIAL NOT NULL, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY
    first_name varchar(20)
    last_name varchar(20)
    address address (composite type)
    contact_numbers varchar(11)[3]
    date_joined date
    type varchar(5)
);
```

and two related tables:

```
CREATE TABLE basic_member (
    activities varchar[3])
    INHERITS (members)
);

CREATE TABLE full_member ( 
    activities varchar[])
    INHERITS (members)
);
```

If the type is `full` the details are entered to the `full_member` table or if type is `basic` into the `basic_member` table. What I want is that if I run an update and change the type to `basic` or `full` the tuple goes into the corresponding table.

I was wondering if I could do this with a rule like:

```
 CREATE RULE tuple_swap_full
 AS ON UPDATE TO full_member
 WHERE new.type = 'basic'
 INSERT INTO basic_member VALUES (old.member_id, old.first_name, old.last_name,
 old.address, old.contact_numbers, old.date_joined, new.type, old.activities);
```

... then delete the record from the full_member

Just wondering if my rule is anywhere near or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need

  ```
  member_id SERIAL NOT NULL, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY
  ```

  A `PRIMARY KEY` implies `UNIQUE NOT NULL` automatically:

  ```
  member_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  ```
- I wouldn't use hard coded max length of `varchar(20)`. Just use [`text`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) and add a check constraint if you really must enforce a maximum length. Easier to change around.
- Syntax for `INHERITS` is mangled. The key word goes outside the parens around columns.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE full_member ( 
      activities text[]
  ) INHERITS (members);
  ```
- Table names are inconsistent (`members` <-> `member`). I use the singular form everywhere in my test case.
- Finally, I would not use a RULE for the task. A **trigger `AFTER UPDATE`** seems preferable.

Consider the following

### Test case:

#### Tables:

```
CREATE SCHEMA x;  -- I put everything in a test schema named "x".

-- DROP TABLE x.members CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE x.member (
     member_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ,first_name text
    -- more columns ...
    ,type text);

CREATE TABLE x.basic_member (
    activities text[3]
) INHERITS (x.member);

CREATE TABLE x.full_member ( 
    activities text[]
) INHERITS (x.member);
```

#### Trigger function:

[Data-modifying CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (`WITH x AS ( DELETE ..`) are the best tool for the purpose. Requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later.
For older versions, first `INSERT` then `DELETE`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.trg_move_member()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

CASE NEW.type
WHEN 'basic' THEN
    WITH x AS (
        DELETE FROM x.member
        WHERE member_id = NEW.member_id
        RETURNING *
        )
    INSERT INTO x.basic_member (member_id, first_name, type) -- more columns
    SELECT member_id, first_name, type -- more columns
    FROM   x;

WHEN 'full' THEN
    WITH x AS (
        DELETE FROM x.member 
        WHERE member_id = NEW.member_id
        RETURNING *
        )
    INSERT INTO x.full_member (member_id, first_name, type) -- more columns
    SELECT member_id, first_name, type -- more columns
    FROM   x;
END CASE;

RETURN NULL;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

#### Trigger:

Note that it is an `AFTER` trigger and has a `WHEN` condition.
`WHEN` condition requires PostgreSQL 9.0 or later. For earlier versions, you can just leave it away, the CASE statement in the trigger itself takes care of it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER up_aft
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON x.member
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.type IN ('basic ','full')) -- OLD.type cannot be IN ('basic ','full')
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE x.trg_move_member();
```

#### Test:

```
INSERT INTO x.member (first_name, type) VALUES ('peter', NULL);

UPDATE x.member SET type = 'full' WHERE first_name = 'peter';
SELECT * FROM ONLY x.member;
SELECT * FROM x.basic_member;
SELECT * FROM x.full_member;
```

Comment: Totally agree on using a trigger instead of a rule.  Rules have a lot of counter-intuitive behaviors and are more likely to burn you in surprising ways than triggers.  I anyone is wondering why they would include a redundant `WHEN` clause -- by dodging the overhead of firing the trigger it helps performance a little.  My preferences on NOT NULL for primary key columns and varchar(n) versus text with constraint match the question, not the answer, but those points have reasonable arguments on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work the Fuction and Trigger can be entered without error but it doesn't work, I can get to the part where i enter a member into x.member that works, but when I run the update i get UPDATE 0 , which obviously means nothing happens.and it doesn't update the x.member table or move it to the x.full_member table :(

Comment: as well im looking to do the edits on either the basic_member table or full_member table. as i add member by either using INSERT INTO basic_member VALUES (ect..) if they are basic member and INSERT INTO full_member VALUES (ect...) if they are full. I just need them to swap if i change type in the basic table to full type or change full to basic in the full table

Comment: @DannyCalladine: There must be a misunderstanding. I tested the code in PostgreSQL 9.1 and it works as per your original question - you only mentioned UPDATE. I would consider to prevent non-matching type in INSERT altogether (add a trigger BEFORE INSERT). And add similar triggers for AFTER UPDATE on the child tables.

Comment: i manag to get it to work basically, i change the first x.member into x.full_member and the second x.member to x.basic_member. then create the same tirgger but the both table instad of just the x.member table. the only thing im wondering now is how i get this to work without the schema or is the schema a must have.

Comment: @DannyCalladine: The schema is just for testing. Remove the schema-qualification `x.` to create / use objects in default schema.